# How to kill a sub task in eclipse which can't run in background?

Tags: eclipse

While moving a java file from one plug-in to another plug-in, a dialog box comes up which asks for confirmation. But in my case what happened is that the move dialog box got hanged and it did not allow me to work any more. And in the end I had to crash the eclipse from task manager. So is there any way by which we can directly close any sub task of eclipse without crashing eclipse itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer is "No". The dialog is modal and as such blocks for input to all other windows/shells, which in turn means you cannot interact with the application.

In theory, one could add a new OSGi console command that could do this and then make an TCP based OSGi console... but... :-)